# Unable to connect to cluster with cqlsh on localhost

Tags: cassandra

I have downloaded the tar binary file and created a cluster with 3 nodes. When running `bin/nodetool` status all the nodes are UN running and when connecting to `bin/cqlsh` it was throwing an error as listed below:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. \
Last error: Connection refused")})
```

The below error is from the logs:

```
ERROR [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2023-06-14 11:40:25,242 HintsCatalog.java:167 - Unable to open directory /home/........../apache-cassandra-4.0.10/bin/../data/hints
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here.

One -

> when connecting to bin/cqlsh it was throwing and error as listed below

```
Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]
```

Curious, but are any of the nodes actually running on localhost (127.0.0.1)?  This should be viewable from the output of the `nodetool status` command.  Try running `bin/cqlsh` while passing one of the bound IP addresses.  Ex:

```
bin/cqlsh 10.4.34.2 -u yourusername -p yourpassword
```

Two -

```
ERROR [HintsWriteExecutor:1] 2023-06-14 11:40:25,242
    HintsCatalog.java:167 - Unable to open directory 
    /home/........../apache-cassandra-4.0.10/bin/../data/hints
```

Which user is Cassandra running as?  Does it have the correct permission to write to the `data/hints/` directory?  I am guessing not.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Connection refused` indicates that there is no process listening for connections on IP `127.0.0.1` on port `9042`.

When you run `cqlsh` without any arguments, it will connect to `localhost` by default.

Since you have deployed a 3-node cluster, that would indicate to me that you have configured each node to use an IP address that is publicly accessible instead of `localhost`.

You need to specify the host using the same address as you configured for `rpc_address` in `cassandra.yaml`. For example:

```
$ bin/cqlsh 10.1.2.3
```

Note that `cqlsh` will connect to the default CQL port `9042`. If you have configured a different `native_transport_port` in `cassandra.yaml`, you also need to specify the port when connecting to your cluster. For example:

```
$ bin/cqlsh 10.1.2.3 9123
```